# How to set own abbr. for citation?

Tags: bibtex, citing

How can I set my own abbreviations for citations? Assuming the following entry in `.bib` file:

```
@book{ChBj,
    title = "Functional Programming in Scala",
    author = "Paul Chiusano and Rúnar Bjarnason",
    year = 2014,
    month = "September",
    isbn = "978-1617290657",
    edition = "1st",
    publisher = "Manning Publications",
}
```

I would like to to display the used `[ChBj]` abbr. instead of `[CB14]`. How can I define that?

I dream of two possible approaches, however I couldn't google any of them:

1. set `\bibliographystyle` so it takes citation name as defined in the file
2. set some special field in citation definicition such as e.g. `abbr = "MyAbbr"`

Is it even possible? If so, is it possible easily? If so, how?

**Edit:**

I use natbib:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

Comment: You can define `shorthands` with `biblatex`, i think the older BibTeX system has a similar mechanism.

Comment: Please advise which bibliography style you use.

Comment: @Mico I hope I clarified it in the edit I made. I hope it helps.

Comment: Can you clarify your set-up.  You give a `bibtex` based coding, but your example entry is `utf8`.  Also `alpha` is not a `natbib` bibliographystyle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `biblatex` package has two citation styles 'draft' and 'debug' which seems to do just that (see the docs with `texdoc biblatex` or through CTAN).

Using the keys actually seems to be useful if you are drafting a document as you can find an entry in your bibliography file fastest through the key.

However if you are planning to use this in a published paper consider using an customary citation style like `authoryear`. Switching to this is just setting an option of the package.

Answer (score 1):

`biblatex` provides a `shorthand` field that you can set in the bibliography database and that will be set instead of the label the biblatex style would print. Here is a short example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @online{texsx,
        author={{The community}},
        url={https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
        shorthand={TeX.SX},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
You can find help reading the \citetitle{companion}
\cite{companion}, but internet communities are also a good place 
\cite{texsx}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: petrbelShorthands]